# Installation cx_Oracle fails

Tags: oracle, installation, cx-oracle

System: MacBook Pro M1 16GB RAM

```py
Python 3.8.5
```

I am trying to install the cx_Oracle module and it doesent work.

`sudo easy_install cx_Oracle` --> Successful

Installed Basic and SDK client from Oracle, after following the installation script in the readme file the copying from the "Stick" completed.

Now the these copied folders are just laying around in my downloads directory, I think, I need to put both clients ([instanclient...]) into a specific directory, but don't know where.
so...

Error when I try to run the python program in the terminal: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "app.py", line 5, in <module> connection = cx_Oracle.connect("hr", "hr", "10.0.0.22/orclpdb") cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 1): image not found". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help`

The Error in pyCharm:
`No module named 'cx_Oracle'`

Also, this solution didnt work for me, because I dont have an oracle folder in /lib https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1244#issuecomment-624646368

Where do I need to put the folders, so that I can use the 'cx_Oracle' module in pyCharm ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note there is no M1 port of the required Oracle Instant Client libraries. Let us know if Apple's Rosetta emulation works for you.  (Also, you don't need the SDK for any recent cx_Oracle versions).

Comment: So, although pyCharm didnt recognized the module (still working on that, ill let you know if I know more) the code did execute and the results were fine. So yes, Rosetta did a fine job translating. Nevertheless, It was mandatory to refer the path to the client with the `cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client()` method, it didnt recognize the client with default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PyCharm Fix below]

I fixed this issue, by using the
`cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client()`command as referenced in the docs.
Although I get the results, it only works in the command line. If I try to use it in pyCharm, it still doesent recognizes my `cx_Oracle` module. (I'll open a new ticket for this error)

This is an example code:

```
import cx_Oracle
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir="/Users/benreisinger/Documents/testclients/instantclient_19_8", config_dir=None, error_url=None, driver_name=None)
# Connect as user "hr" with password "welcome" to the "orclpdb1" service running on this computer.
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("hr", "hr", "10.0.0.22/orclpdb")

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
        select e.first_name AS fname, e.last_name AS lname, e.department_id, d.department_name
            from employees e 
            inner join departments d 
                on (e.department_id = d.department_id)
        """)

for first_name, last_name, department_id, department_name in cursor:
    print("Values:", first_name, last_name, department_id, department_name)
```

Results only in the terminal !

FIX: PyCharm->preferences->Project:[your Project]-> Python Interpreter-> add cx-Oracle package

--> With this fix, finally, PyCharm recognized the cx_Oracle module :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions found in the documentation located here: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html.

So long as cx_Oracle is installed in the Python used by PyCharm you should be able to see it.

Comment: The problem is, that I dont know how to do this step: `Add Oracle 19, 18, 12 or 11.2 client libraries to your operating system library search path such as PATH on Windows or LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Linux. On macOS use init_oracle_client() in your application to pass the Oracle Client directory name, see Locating the Oracle Client Libraries. This is also usable on Windows.`

Comment: So, the problem I think is, that Python doesent know where to search for the installed clients. Still bizarre, that i get the error: `No module named 'cx_Oracle' `.

Comment: If I try to run the python program via terminal: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 5, in <module>
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect("hr", "hr", "10.0.0.22/orclpdb")
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 1): image not found". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help`